# big struct init in C

Tags: c, initialization, embedded, structure

I have got a choice to do to initialize a big structure in C.
I am working on an embedded micro with a tiny memory size.
I've got the chip configuration saved in EEPROM.
So I have a struct which contain all the configuration page in EEPROM :

```
Typedef struct
{
    unsigned int Param1;
    float Param2;
    unsigned char Param3;
    [...]
    char Paramx[SIZE];
} T_EEPROM;
```

We have to keep in mind that this struct is heavy regarding the tiny memory size of the micro.

I have a global variable of this type :

```
T_EEPROM MyConfig;
```

This is used to modify or access EEPROM configuration :

```
MyConfig.Param1 = NewValue;
WriteEEPROM(MyConfig);
```

Now I want to initialize this variable with diffrents kind of factory configurations (CONFIG A, CONFIG B, etc)
All the parameters for each factory configuration can be defined by a #define

After that, I don't know which method to use :

1) Write an initialization function which take all the values in parameters :

```
bool InitEEPROM(unsigned int param1, float param2, unsigned char param3, [...], char *Paramx)
{
    MyConfig.Param1 = param1;
    MyConfig.Param2 = param2;
    MyConfig.Param3 = param3;
    [...]
    MyConfig.Paramx = paramx;
}
```

After, I could call the function lake that :

```
void InitFactoryEEPROM (unsigned char type)
{
    if (type == 1)
        InitEEPROM(DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_1, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_1,DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_1, [...], DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_1);
    else if (type == 2)
        InitEEPROM(DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_2, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_2,DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_2, [...], DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_2);
    else if (type == 3)
        [...]
}
```

Disadventage: heavy to write

2) Create a big array with all the factory configurations :

```
T_EEPROM FactoryEepromConfig[CONFIG_COUNT] =
{
    {DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_1, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_1, DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_1, [...], DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_1},
    {DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_2, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_2,DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_2, [...], DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_2},
    [...]
};
```

With an easier initialisation function:

```
bool InitEEPROM(T_EEPROM factoryConfig)
{
    MyConfig.Param1 = factoryConfig.Param1 ;
    MyConfig.Param2 = factoryConfig.Param2;
    MyConfig.Param3 = factoryConfig.Param3;
    [...]
    MyConfig.Paramx = factoryConfig.Paramx;
}
```

And this call:

```
void InitFactoryEEPROM (unsigned char type)
{
    InitEEPROM(FactoryEepromConfig[type]);
}
```

Disadventage:
Very heavy in memory because I have a `T_EEPROM` instance for each factory configuration.

Anyone has got a better idea?

Comment: Can configuration change at runtime ?

Comment: Are you saying that your various configurations only set a few fields, and you don't really know which fields? If that is the case you could write a function for each config that sets the fields it needs setting, then have a table of function pointers. Another option might be to pre-process the configurations into a runlength encoding, where runs of zeros are compacted. The code to unpack is trivial.

Comment: I would prefer the second but instead of a copy I would pass a pointer

Comment: Whis MCU is this? If it has a tiny memory size, then why do you use floating point? I am not aware of any MCU with tiny memory size which contains a FPU. Yet you drag in a whole software float library, slaughtering what little memory there was in the first place.

Comment: Also, I completely misunderstood the question. The function `InitEEPROM` actually initializes RAM, not EEPROM, correct? If so, is there a reason why you must keep a full RAM image of the EEPROM in memory, rather than to read directly from EEPROM just when needed? This comes at the cost of a few extra cycles at worst, but saves a ton of memory. Or is this some dysfunctional Harvard thing where you can't easily access data in EEPROM?

Comment: Hi,Configuration can change at runtime.

Comment: The MCU is a STM32, I can do float operations and need it due to the nature of the software (meteo measures)

Comment: InitEEPROM initialize the strut in RAM, afet I can update the EEPROM with a function like "WriteEEPROM(MyConfig);"

Comment: "STM32" could mean anything. I take it it's a Cortex M3 or bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is short and clean:

```
static const T_EEPROM FactoryEepromConfig[CONFIG_COUNT] =
{
{DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_1, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_1, DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_1, [...],     DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_1},
{DEFINE_PARAM1_CONFIG_2, DEFINE_PARAM2_CONFIG_2,DEFINE_PARAM3_CONFIG_2, [...],     DEFINE_PARAMx_CONFIG_2},
[...]
};

void InitFactoryEEPROM (size_t type)
{
    assert(type < CONFIG_COUNT);
    MyConfig = FactoryEepromConfig[type];
}
```

to avoid globals you can change the function to this:

```
void InitFactoryEEPROM (T_EEPROM* config, size_t type)
{
    assert(type < CONFIG_COUNT);
    *config = FactoryEepromConfig[type];
}
```

Comment: The function is almost useless, and the big array will be in memory, so you loose a lot of space.

Comment: Thats right but if you want all configurations at runtime you have to store them somewhere.

Comment: In this case just keep the index or a pointer to the curent configuration is the way to go.

Comment: To keep a pointer on the current config would be the best choice I agree, but I can't. I have simplified the problem to present it on the forum, but I have to copy the conf in the EEPROM

Comment: If I declare the big array in static const, it will be placed in RAM othertheless ? Because I don't want to have all the array in RAM during all the execution time

Comment: `const` variables should normaly be in flash not on RAM

Answer (score 2):

In all the scenario's (possibilities) you gave, the values need to be in memory, either as variables or as values to initialize variables with. So there is not much difference in the memory footprint. Using initialization functions has the overhead of code bytes required to execute the initialization.

Having one static array containing all the values, and that you index every time you need a value, has the overhead of instructions to index the array. Copying the values of an array index to a "working set" variable has the overhead of the extra variable.

Possibly you can measure which is smallest by making several versions, e.g.:

- one static array that is indexed for each parameter access;
- one static array and copying the working set to an extra variable;
- initializing a working set variable using an initialization function.

But this assumes the working set of values can change during execution. If they don;t change, then you can use `#define`s to select the working set of values and use that for static initialization of the working set variables.